# SELinux process contexts

Tags: selinux

Can I run two processes from the same binary with SELinux in enforcing mode with an MLS policy that have different MLS contexts?

Let's say I have a binary `/usr/bin/foo`. I want to launch one process of `foo` and have it running with the context:

```
user_u:role_r:domain_t:s0-s0:c14,c45
```

I then want to launch another process with different command line options and have it running with the context:

```
user_u:role_r:domain_t:s0-s0:c28,c67
```

Is this possible? If so, is it easy?